# How do I route to a different location based on the values selected from a dropdown in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am writing an app which has many horizontal user flows and we are using a dropdown in the landing page to enable users to choose what they want.. and based on what they select from the dropdown, the submit button must take them to a corresponding view. Something like this:

```
               ----value1---------> /userdetails
  Landing page ----value2---------> /confirm
               ----value3---------> /moreinfo
```

the number of values might get quite large very soon.They are populated from a RESTful response. I can modify the response to include a type attribute for each option and use a map in JS(attribute:route) to route to dynamic locations. But I think there might be a more robust way to do this.. but cant think of any..Any help ppl?

Answer (score 0):

simply add:

```
onchange="navigator.location.href=this.value;"
```

to your combo box. (and make sure that the values are the appropriate route locations.

Comment: As I said, the dropdown is populated from the backend.. so this will require me to fetch the route locations from backend, correct?

Comment: ng-repeat would most likely be the best way to create the combo box options. although if it is a more static option then it is always possible to simply generate the code when constructing the page via the backend.

Comment: I am not constructing the page on the backend.. I am fetching the values from an API call and using ng-repeat to render them on the front-end.

Comment: Well in which case build it on the client side, with data from your restful api.